# Searching by Index in a LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I have created my own LinkedList which contains a Song object(title, artist etc..). I am trying to add a function where the user inputs an index location and the information about the Song is displayed at that specific index. I am having trouble getting the location of the index. Currently every time I run this it can not find the information at the index. I am not sure if I need to implement a search function or if I am just searching for it incorrectly.

**How I am currently trying to search by index**

```
System.out.print("Enter song index location: ");
int searchIndex = input.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    if ( list.get(i).getValue().equals(searchIndex) ){
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getValue());
            found = true;
    }
}
if ( found != true ){
    System.out.println("Song does not exist.");
}
```

**This is my LinkedList class**

```
public class LinkedList {
private Node first;
private Node last;
public LinkedList(){
    first = null;
    last = null;
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return first == null;
}
public int size(){
    int count = 0;
    Node p = first;
    while( p != null ){
        count++;
        p = p.getNext();
    }
    return count;
}
public Node get( int i ){
    Node prev = first;
    for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){
        prev = prev.getNext();
}
    return prev;
}
public String toString(){
    String str = "";
    Node n = first;
    while( n != null ){
        str = str + n.getValue() + " ";
         n = n.getNext();
    }
    return str;
}
public void add( Song c ){
    if( isEmpty() ) {
        first = new Node(c);
        last = first;
    }else{
        Node n = new Node(c);
        last.setNext(n);
        last = n;
    }
}
```

**Node Class**

```
public class Node {
private Song song;
private Node next;
public Node( Song s ){
    song = s;
    next = null;
}
public Node( Song s, Node n ){
    song = s;
    next = n;
}
public Node getNext(){
    return next;
}
public void setNext(Node n){
    next = n;
}
public Song getValue(){
    return song;
}
public void setValue( Song s ){
    song = s;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're searching based on the value rather than the index.  Do you want to just get the index that the user enters?

Comment: why do u need the outer for loop in your search method ?

Comment: @DanielNugent Yes, I understand i am searching incorrectly. I just want to get the index the user enters and display the information that is at that index.

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan I am iterating through the LinkedList there.

Comment: you dont need to iterate there . the iteration part for the search is done inside the get (int i) method of the linkedlist isn't it ?

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan You are correct the for loop is not needed in this situation. Thank You.

Comment: You can also do away with the if condition and make it simpler :if ( list.get(searchIndex)!=null ){
            System.out.println(list.get(searchIndex).getValue());
            found = true;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is all you need to do given the functionality you have in your `LinkedList`:

```
System.out.print("Enter song index location: ");
int searchIndex = input.nextInt();
if (searchIndex >= 0 && searchIndex < list.size(){ 
   System.out.println(list.get(searchIndex).getValue());
}
else{
    System.out.println("Song does not exist.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a linked list, you have to iterate through the whole list (iterating the curr node) in order the find an object.

Your search should look something like:

```
if (list.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("Song does not exist.");
}

boolean found = false;
int searchIndex = input.nextInt();

Node current = list;
    while(current != null){
        if(current.equals(searchIndex)){
        found = true; //found song
        break;
        }
    current = current.next;
    }
return current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like a linear search by Song. You're checking if the value entered (an int, searchIndex) matches Nody.getValue(), which returns a Song.

If you're trying to get by index, seems like you would simply call LinkedList.get(searchIndex)?

Additionally:

- There should be no reason to store that last node, as you don't have a doubly-linked list (which you can navigate from either end). You only need the first Node, and then you use Node.next() to navigate.
- It'd probably me more performant to maintain the count by incrementing it on calls to add(), and decrementing it when calling remove().
- You should probably do bounds checking on the get() method:

  ```
  public Node get(int i) {
      if (i >= size()) {
          throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
      }
      Node n = first;
      int j = 0;
      while (i != j) {
          n = n.getNext();
      }
      return n;
  }
  ```
- Establish a coding style and stick to it! You sometimes have spaces around parameters, and sometimes you don't. Sometimes a space before an opening brace, sometimes you don't. The above is what I do.